# C# LINQ Aggregate converts string to int

Tags: c#, linq, type-conversion, aggregate

I am playing around with a level on CodeHunt.com and I simply can't understand why in the following code the VisualStudio/Codehunt compilers want the Aggregate function to convert from strings back to int when the assigned type is supposed to be IEnumerable < string  >

```
using System;
using System.Linq;
class Program {
    static void Main(string[] args) {
        Console.WriteLine(Puzzle(4)); //supposed to return "0____ 01___ 012__ 0123_ 01234 "
        Console.ReadLine();
    }
    public static string Puzzle(int n) {
        IEnumerable<int> enunums = Enumerable.Range(0, n);
        IEnumerable<string> enustrings = enunums.Aggregate((a, b) => a.ToString() + b.ToString() + new string('_', n - b) + " ");
        return string.Join("", enustrings);
    }
}
```

Comment: this code doesn't compile

Comment: well that is the problem

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First off, there are always two distinct steps:

1. Call the function and get the result
2. Try to assign the result to a variable

The first step does not even consider the left hand side variable (in your case, `IEnumerable<string>`). It only looks at the declaration of the function.

As per the documentation of the [`Aggregate`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb548651.aspx) function, the declaration is:

```
public static TSource Aggregate<TSource>(this IEnumerable<TSource> source,
                                         Func<TSource, TSource, TSource> func);
```

Notice the part where it takes in an `IEnumerable<TSource>`. Because you call `enunums.Aggregate`, `TSource` becomes assigned to `int`. Since this TSource is used everywhere, including the second function argument and the return type, it naturally expects `int` everywhere i.e. the final form returns a simple `int`.

```
public static int Aggregate<int>(this IEnumerable<int> source,
                                 Func<int, int, int> func);
```

You can call another overload of [`Aggregate`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb549218.aspx), which takes a seed input of another type and then appends to it:

```
public static TAccumulate Aggregate<TSource, TAccumulate>(this IEnumerable<TSource> source,
                                                          TAccumulate seed,
                                                          Func<TAccumulate, TSource, TAccumulate> func);
```

which will translate to:

```
public static string Aggregate<int, string>(this IEnumerable<int> source,
                                            string seed,
                                            Func<string, int, string> func);
```

This should return the final result `string`, not a list of strings.

However, any `Aggregate` function only works in terms of pairs of elements in the list. So your logic will have to be significantly different from what's currently written.

Comment: Part of your comment did not get posted

Comment: Okay,
var enustring = enunums.Aggregate("", (total, next) => total.ToString() + next.ToString() + new string('_', n - next) + " ");

// returns "0____ 1___ 2__ 3_ " but I should be able to fix this. thanks